Distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input in Javascript
I have parcel search input, where you can search parcels with a barcode, you can enter the barcode both with the keyboard and with the scanner. I need to clear the old input value when the user scans a new one.
I work with Javascript and As far as I can see, javascript can't distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input, so I use time base. At the moment I don't have a scanner and I use a phone scanner with the Barcode2win app when I test my script it works well, but when a customer checks out with a scanner it doesn't work, it just prints the barcode's  only last 4 number.
This is my script
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const input = document.getElementById("searchParcels");
    let lastKeyTime = 0;
    let inputBuffer = "";
    const barcodeThreshold = 50; // Time threshold for detecting barcode scanner input
    const typingDelay = 200; // Delay to determine if it's keyboard input
    let typingTimer;

    function processInput(page = 1) {
        let search_string = input.value;
        
        fetch(
            `${searchRoute}/search?query=${encodeURIComponent(
                search_string
            )}&page=${page}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                },
            }
        )
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                document.querySelector(".parcels-list-container").innerHTML =
                    data;
                attachPaginationLinks(search_string);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
    }

    function clearInput() {
        input.value = "";
        inputBuffer = "";
    }

    function attachPaginationLinks(query = "") {
        const paginationLinks = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".parcels-list-container .pagination a"
        );
        paginationLinks.forEach((link) => {
            link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const url = new URL(this.href);
                const page = url.searchParams.get("page");
                processInput(page);
            });
        });
    }

    input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        const timeDifference = currentTime - lastKeyTime;

        if (timeDifference < barcodeThreshold) {
            if (e.key.length === 1) {
                inputBuffer += e.key;
            }

            if (inputBuffer.length > 0) {
                clearInput();
                input.value = inputBuffer;
                inputBuffer = "";
                processInput();
            }
        } else {
            
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            typingTimer = setTimeout(() => processInput(), typingDelay);
            inputBuffer = "";
        }

        lastKeyTime = currentTime;
    });
});


Why don't you clear the number as soon as you act on it?

Does it matter when it is cleaned?
Should it be scanned correctly in both cases?

Well, the KEY is knowing when you're done with the first entry and are starting a second one.  If there is a "Go" button, then obviously you clear the box during that processing.  If you're just relying on the number of digits, then again you have some signal that says "this entry is finished".  There's no point in leaving the number displayed after you've processed it.  Right?

The answers given in these articles may give you some ideas. How do I distinguish between a scanner input and keyboard input in Javascript?, How to differentiate the input from hand held scanner/ gun scanner and from keyboard in jQuery?, How to detect what barcode scanner (emulated as USB keyboard input) data came from
